Blazor client: token from OIDC, but roles from backend API, unable to do that properly
I have a project written in Blazor WASM on .NET 8.0. I use OpenID Connect to receive a token for authentication (which works fine!).
I want to use my backend for authorization, roles management.
On the backend it was easy to set it up by creating a custom IAuthorizationFilter. Alas! While I can create a custom AuthorizeAttribute on the client, I can't make it a proper filter, like on the backend. I then found that creating a custom AuthenticationStateProvider should be the way.
But according to this post, it doesn't work anymore: .NET 7 Blazor WebAssembly - IAuthorizationHandler not being called when policy is used
I even tried Copilot, basically it produces either code that doesn't work for Blazor WASM, or it propose stuff that isn't optimal, like creating a component for authorization that would redirect (but the page would almost be loaded, API would be called, resulting in errors popping up to the user!).
If a custom AuthenticationStateProvider doesn't work, I am thinking creating a custom AuthorizeView component that would call a service that check the rights on the server. But that means recreating a lot of existing core component! Not optimal at all!
Input greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Do you mean you want to add role-based authorization in your blazor web assembly app? And in your scenario, you used external auth provider to sign in users but the user roles information can only be obtained from backend service? If so, do you think this blog is helpful to you?

Hello,
Yes it is exactly as you phrase it.
I already saw tutorial like the one you put, but in this one the backend is responsible to generate the jwt token. It's way easier this way as we can just put the roles inside the token.
In my case, the token come from an external openid provider. But I want to call an api on my backend to obtain the roles.

Thank you for your update, since then I'm afraid you'd integrate jwt authentication scheme in your API project so that you can generate access token which containing the custom role. Otherwize you still needs to modify the toekn obtained from external openid provider to add the custom role into it...
